# ProxyPass Failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: php, web-services, sockets, proxypass

I have written a WebSocket Server on PHP/Apache. I made the WebSocket Secure using mod_proxy_wstunnel. 
So, a user connects with WSS://socket.domain.com and the request is redirected to the (WS) protocol, e.g: ws://10.21.55.2:12345/
I'm using proxy pass just because the page is loaded over HTTPS and WwebSocket is on WS protocol.

here is how I redirect WSS ==> WS for `socket.domain.com`

```
ProxyPass / ws://10.21.55.2:12345
```

but the above code is giving 500 Internal Server Error. I dont know why its so. It was working before I rebooted the system.

here is the error log

```
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Comment: I am also facing this same issues, How can we resolved this one ??

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add the mod proxy_wstunnel
`a2enmod proxy_wstunnel`